# Does iOS have a 'Notification Listener'?

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification

Is it possible to create a Notification Listener in iOS? Something like the [**NotificationListenerService**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) in *Android*.

**Edit:** What I want to do is listen to any notifications coming from any app within the device (missed calls, emails, SMS...)

Comment: What sort of notifications do you want to listen for? Do you mean notifications within the app? Or push notifications from Apple?

Comment: Push notifications from any app (phone calls, emails, instant messages...) as the NotificationListenerService in Android does. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible answer for this.

`NSNotificationCenter` is used to post notifications within the app itself. Say for instance you want several classes all to receive information that something has happened (or something) then you would use this.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you mean `Remote Notifications` i.e. push notifications that you receive from Apple then the AppDelegate receives these in a couple of its methods...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW16

**Edit:** It's not possible between apps. See comments.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. I haven't developed anything for iOS yet but in Android you can use a NotificationListenerService to listen to notifications from any app not just within the app itself [or Apple], is that possible in iOS? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, no between apps isn't possible. The OS sandboxes every app making it impossible to communicate between them (as a security thing) There is "inter-app audio" but not 100% certain what that is but anything else no.

Comment: I was afraid so. Thanks.