# iOS - Notification listener?

Tags: ios, notifications, homekit

Motivation: I am using an iPad for my house automation. My doorbell is a ring.com doorbell which sends a notification to my iPad if someone rings. There is no way to configure the ring app to open the live view if someone rings. I need to tap on the incoming notification.

Does anybody now a good framework for iOS that can handle that? I want to write my own small app that waits till the notification comes up and simulate the tap.

Comment: This is not the place to ask about other apps. This is a site for asking programming questions. So please reduce your question to just the programming aspect.

Comment: Sorry. Changed my question...

Comment: Helpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073886/does-ios-have-a-notification-listener