# Listening to incoming notifications Flutter

Tags: flutter, cross-platform

I am deciding whether to use Flutter for cross platform app. I have investigated in ways to implement other functionalities.

But I need one other feature to implement which needs listening to incoming notification from other app in background. (something like [notification listener in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService))

While I was searching came across the issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24278) which may effect what I intend to implement.

Is there any way to achieve what I want in Flutter?
I am willing to write plugins in native languages if its possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can benefit from [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to write a plugin to utilise native code for each platforms. This [medium post](https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) explains how to execute dart in the background and have example code for Android (Kotlin) and iOS (Objective-C).

However, according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22073980/3266152) you are not able to create an similar service like a NotificationListener for iOS.